# Custom Post - additional param in the custom post URL goes to error page

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, multisite, urls

I've a custom post which when a new post is created, the url for the post generated is

```
http://localhost:8888/wolves/category/barks/
```

which is by default using the Wordpress category and it's working fine, the problem occurs when i add one more param to the url like :

```
http://localhost:8888/wolves/category/barks/sort/az
```

This url is redirecting to 404 - Error Page.

Comment: Hmmm - any reason why you are adding "parameters" as path elements? i.e. why not use `http://localhost:8888/wolves/category/barks/?sort=az` ?

Comment: how are you adding those ?

Comment: I tried with - http://localhost:8888/wolves/category/barks/?sort=az, it's working..